# How to set MySQL ANSI_QUOTES mode via MySQL Java Connector?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, mysql-connector

I have a Scala (Java) Play Web Application where I wrap database identifiers with ANSI double-quotes in queries e.g.

```
select * 
from "account" 
where "deleted" is null
order by "account_name"
```

This is necessary because I use among others H2 in-memory and Postgres databases for deploying the application in different scenarios e.g. CI server. Now we need to deploy it also in MySQL and by default wrapping identifiers in double-quotes is not supported. However, following directions from this post [mysql double-quoted table names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884854/mysql-double-quoted-table-names) I see we can set this session parameter and then it should work.

How can I set this session parameter while opening the connection through the MySQL Java Connector? My database URL looks like this: `jdbc:mysql://odysseus:3306/idxsrs-trading?param=xxx`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Mysql session variable in JDBC string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702120/mysql-session-variable-in-jdbc-string)

Using the above to link in combination with the link you've posted, I'd try this. 
    `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?sessionVariables=sql_mode=ANSI_QUOTES`